# Given a list of tuples: Find duplicates and move them with the most effective way

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I got two Python lists with some data:

```
list_first = [(1, 2, 'Adam', 'Men', '3.5', '1'),
              (1, 2, 'Ewa', 'Women', '2', '1'),
              (1, 2, 'Adam', 'Men', '4', '2')]

second_list = [(2, 5, 'Jack', 'Men', '3.5', '1'),
               (1, 3, 'Chris', 'Women', '5', '2'),
               (10, 22, 'Adam', 'Men', '42', '11')]
```

Now I want to find duplicates in the `second_list`, but only with Name and Sex field, so in the above example:

The duplicate in the `second_list` is Adam. (Adam, Men).

Now I want tmove this tuple `((1, 2, 'Adam', 'Man', '4', '2'))` to `list_first`.

I tried to make it in the following way:
(without success):

```
name_fy = [(item[2] for item in list_first) and
           (item[3] for item in list_first)]
name_sy = [(item[2] for item in list_second) and
           (item[3] for item in list_second)]

for i in name_fy :
  for j in name_sy :
    if i == j:
      # move to list_first
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single list comprehension with `any`:

```
list_first = [(1, 2, 'Adam', 'Men', '3.5', '1'), (1, 2, 'Ewa', 'Women', '2', '1'), (1, 2, 'Adam', 'Man', '4', '2')]
second_list = [(2, 5, 'Jack', 'Men', '3.5', '1'), (1, 3, 'Chris', 'Women', '5', '2'), (10, 22, 'Adam', 'Man', '42', '11')]
list_first += [i for i in second_list if any(x[2] == i[2] and x[3] == i[3] for x in list_first)]
second_list = list(filter(lambda x:not any(a[2] == x[2] and a[3] == x[3] for a in list_first), second_list))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 'Adam', 'Men', '3.5', '1'), (1, 2, 'Ewa', 'Women', '2', '1'), (1, 2, 'Adam', 'Man', '4', '2'), (10, 22, 'Adam', 'Man', '42', '11')]
[(2, 5, 'Jack', 'Men', '3.5', '1'), (1, 3, 'Chris', 'Women', '5', '2')]
```

Comment: How i should remove the duplicates which I added in list_first from second_list ?

Comment: @WaterInTheButtle Please see my recent edit. That can be accomplished by using `filter`.

Comment: I owe you one! Thanks!

Comment: You can use single comprehension for inserting into `list_first` and removal from `second_list`.    `list_first +=[k[1] for k in enumerate(second_list) if any(x[2] == k[1][2] and x[3] == k[1][3] and second_list.pop(k[0]) for x in list_first)]`